# how boolean values are treated in java by bit wise operators

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

consider this example please

```
int i=11, j=5;
boolean b=true, c=false;
System.out.println(b&c); // --> output=false
System.out.println(i&j); // --> output=1
```

How bit wise and operator is working on boolean variables ?

Comment: I would like to point out that the reason & and | can be used on booleans is that they do not short circuit, whereas && and || do short circuit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no bitwise operations on `boolean` in Java.

`&` and `|` don't do bitwise operations in Java, but [logical operations (as specified in §15.22.2 of the **JLS**)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.2).

- `&` is the logical AND (it will evaluate to `true` if and only if both arguments are `true`)
- `|` is the logical OR (it will evaluate to `true` if and only if at least one of the arguments is `true`).

Note that the **same** operators are used for [bitwise operations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.1), but those only apply when both operands are of a type that is convertible to an integral type (i.e. `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and their respective wrappers).

Since this post led to some ... spirited discussion, I think I'll clarify my insistence on the difference between "bitwise" and "logical" operations.

First of: **Yes**, at *some* level, the two operations will work exactly the same, except for the size of their input (which might even be identical, due to optimizations).

*But*, there are at lest 3 levels here:

- The Java language

  [The Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) defines `boolean` as [a primitive type with the two values `true` and `false`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.5). It does **not** define numeric values for those values and there is no direct way to convert it to a numeric type or vice versa (see last sentence of [§4.2.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.2))
- The Java Virtual Machine

  [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html) [defines the `boolean` type](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#22909) but provides very little support for it.

  It also says this about conversions

  > The Java virtual machine encodes `boolean` array components using 1 to represent true and 0 to represent false. Where Java programming language `boolean` values are mapped by compilers to values of Java virtual machine type `int`, the compilers must use the same encoding.

  The *easiest* way to fullfil this requirement in a JVM is obviously to let `1` be `true` and `0` be false and let the conversion operation be a no-op. That's also the most likely implementation, but it's not **necessarily** the only correct implementation.
- The Hardware

  This varies a lot, but most CPUs don't have support for a `boolean` type (why should they?) so operations on `boolean` will use normal bitwise operations here.

Comment: if u observe above output when we are doing biwise on integer it is performing absolutly perfect. but when we come to bit wise operations on boolean it it is retuning eaither true or false.... what actually jvm internally doing while working with bitwise operations on boolean variables.... Is it going to take true means internally a numerical value?

Comment: I agree that this is boolean logic, but it is still considered a bitwise operation.  You also forgot to mention bitshifts.

Comment: **There are no bitwise operations on `boolean` in Java**. It's as simple as that. What happens in the sample above (`a&b`) is a logical and, as specified in the JLS (see the link in my answer).

Comment: if we perform operations on boolean using shift operators it is throwing error

Comment: @Jaochim I never said shifting a boolean.  He also gave integer values, which can be shifted if necessary.

Comment: @Trevor: but he asked "how are **boolean** values treated" (emphasis mine).

Comment: what is the dfualt value taken by jvm for true in java?

Comment: @Joachim A bitwise operation is simply taking the variable's binary numeral at the level of their bits.  A boolean value is just considered to a be `0` or `1`

Comment: @Joachim All the trusted sources never clarify what `true` and `false` are but it is intuitive that a boolean value is 1 bit, either a `1` or a `0`.  Do you really believe that on the machine level a boolean's value is `true` and `false`?

Comment: @Trevor: no, that's not what I believe. But at the *language level* in *Java* a `boolean` has no numeric value. In pretty much the same way as a *reference* has no numeric value. Of course: at one point or another it hits the metal and it *will* be a number, but that's not "at the Java level".

Comment: @Joachim Who cares about language level.  Nothing is language level once compiled

Comment: @Trevor: the reason I'm so insistent on this is not my ego (which is fine, thanks ;-)), but that this is an important difference to C (and some C-based languages): `boolean` is a type in its own right and not just a "very small integer". The JLS treats it that way and it probably has a good reason to do that.

Comment: @Joachim If I said it was a small integer, I apologize.  I said it was a binary number...see Peters answer

Comment: @Trevor: I've decided to move my attempted explanations to the answer, where they can be more explicit. Does that look more sensible than what I posted in my comments?

Answer (score 9):

For boolean type:

The operators `&` and `&&` are treated as logical AND

The operators `|` and `||` are treated as logical OR.

You also have `^` which performs XOR and `!` which performs a NOT.

---

How does this work in the JVM and how does it compare with bit-wise integer operations?

At the byte code level, FALSE has the value 0 and TRUE has the value. From the `javap -c java.lang.Boolean`

```
static {};
  Code:
   0:   new     #56; //class java/lang/Boolean
   3:   dup
   4:   iconst_1
   5:   invokespecial   #89; //Method "<init>":(Z)V
   8:   putstatic       #86; //Field TRUE:Ljava/lang/Boolean;
   11:  new     #56; //class java/lang/Boolean
   14:  dup
   15:  iconst_0
   16:  invokespecial   #89; //Method "<init>":(Z)V
   19:  putstatic       #85; //Field FALSE:Ljava/lang/Boolean;
```

In this code it is defining TRUE as `new Boolean(true)` and you can see that `true` is pushed onto the stack using `iconst_1` which is like push(1)  Similarly `iconst_0` or `0` is used for `false`

If you map `false` <=> `0` and `true` <=> `1` you can see that `&` and `|` work the same way for `int` and `boolean`

Answer (score 4):

For your case, I believe the only difference b/w `&` and `&&` is the fact that for `&`, the second operand will still be evaluated even if the first operand evaluates to false, while in the case of `&&` the second operand is not evaluated if the first evaluates to false.

Mostly relevant if you have a costly method in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

The first operation you do -  TRUE & FALSE is taken as 1 & 0, which is false.

The second operation - 11 & 5 is taken as 1011 & 0101 (the binary values), which is 0001 when anded.