# How do i make an if statement if one is a pair and other is not it is not lucky but if both is a pair it is lucky?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have my if-else if-else statement to be
Edit (New code):

```
    for (int counter = 1; counter<3; counter++) {
        A = rand.nextInt(MAX_DICE) + 1;
        B = rand.nextInt(MAX_DICE) + 1;
        C = rand.nextInt(MAX_DICE) + 1;
        System.out.println(A + " " + B + " " + C);

        if (A == B & A == C) {
            System.out.println("You rolled 3 of a kind.");
            pairs += 1;
        }
        else if (A == B || A == C || B == C) {
            System.out.println("You rolled a pair.");
            pairs += 2;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You rolled nothing.");
            pairs += 3;
        }
    }
    if (pairs >= 3) {
        System.out.println("You are NOT lucky.");
    }
    else if (pairs >= 2)
        System.out.println("You are lucky.");
    else {
        System.out.println("You are lucky.");
      }
   } 
}
```

How do I make it so after the coding statements it would say if it had 2 pairs of pairs (eg. a pair and pair) or pair and triple the result would end up as You are lucky, but if it had only 1 pair and nothing or no pairs it would say you are not lucky?

For example:

> 4 5 3
> You rolled nothing.
> 2 1 3
> You rolled nothing.
> You are NOT lucky.
>
> 4 5 3
> You rolled nothing.
> 2 2 2
> You rolled 3 of a kind.
> You are NOT lucky.
>
> 4 4 3
> You rolled a pair.
> 2 2 2
> You rolled 3 of a kind.
> You are lucky.
>
> 4 3 3
> You rolled a pair.
> 2 1 2
> You rolled a pair.
> You are lucky.

Edit: Right now it is giving me You are NOT lucky. For everything, even for the double pair rolls or a pair and triple roll

Comment: `if (A == B & A == C)` should be `if (A == B && A == C)`

Comment: So you're saying you need to count the number of special outcomes the user got? Can you create a variable that does that, which you can then check at the end?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you roll 3 of a kind are you lucky or not?

Comment: @FlorentBayle If its java then It will work as Bitwise operators do logical 'and' and 'or' on boolean values as expected.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911063/how-boolean-values-are-treated-in-java-by-bit-wise-operators

Comment: The question was that it rolls twice, whether it can be a pair and a pair or pair and a triple or a triple and a triple or a pair and nothing or triple and nothing or both as nothing.

Comment: OF course it is since you add +3 for every bad throw. Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Going full Lambda/Streams you could do

```
import static java.util.stream.IntStream.*;

public static int roll() {
    return rand.nextInt(MAX_DICE) + 1;
}

int tests = 2;
int dice = 3;
int pairs = range(0, tests)
       .filter($-> range(0, dice).map(_-> roll()).distinct().count() < dice)
       .count();
```

if the number of tests is likely to be large you can do

```
int pairs = (tests > 100 ? range(0, tests).parallel() : range(0, tests))
       .filter($-> range(0, dice).map(_-> roll()).distinct().count() < dice)
       .count();
```

One way you can do this is in Java 8

```
switch(IntStream.of(A, B, C).distinct().count()) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("You rolled 3 of a kind.");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("You rolled a pair.");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("You rolled different numbers.");
        break;
}
```

To do similar in Java 7 or older.

```
int count = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(A, B, C)).size();
```

If you want to count these you can do

```
int pairs = 0;
for (int counter = 1; counter<= 2; counter++) {
    // on a six sides dice you want 1 to 6 not 0 to 6
    int a = rand.nextInt(MAX_DICE) + 1;
    int b = rand.nextInt(MAX_DICE) + 1;
    int c = rand.nextInt(MAX_DICE) + 1;

    // triples count as pairs.
    if (IntStream.of(A, B, C).distinct().count() < 3)
       pairs++;
}
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do a distinct count like that, nice! +1

Comment: @KevinPaton See if you can work out what `$->` and `_->` does ;)

Comment: Monads! Thats cool, I've seen those in haskell before, I admit I had help from this tutorial though http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

Comment: What is '$' used for? Why do you need it?

Comment: @KevinPaton It's not used, which is why I didn't give it name.  You have to include it as the function has t take an input even if you don't need it.

Comment: if (IntStream.of(A, B, C).distinct().count() < 3) pairs++; won't add 2 on a three of a kind.
pairs += (3 - IntStream.of(A, B, C).distinct().count()) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

That code is a mess.  Don't mingle printing a message to the console with determining outcomes.  Create an `Outcome` class with a method called `isLucky()` that returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, how about putting your three Integers A,B,C to a `Set<Integer>`, then check the size of the set, if the size is

```
1 -> 3 times same
2 -> pair
3 -> nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int pairs = 0;
for (int counter = 1; counter < 3; counter++) {
    A = rand.nextInt(MAX_DICE + 1);
    B = rand.nextInt(MAX_DICE + 1);
    C = rand.nextInt(MAX_DICE + 1);
    System.out.println(A + " " + B + " " + C);


    if (A == B && A == C) {
        System.out.println("You rolled 3 of a kind.");
        pairs += 2; //a three of a kind is worth as much as two times a pair
    }
    else if (A == B || A == C || B==C) {
        System.out.println("You rolled a pair.");
        pairs += 1; //one pair
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You rolled nothing.");
        //don't add pairs += here because whe don't have a pair
    }
}
//You can change the value:
// 4 = only lucky with 2 three of a kinds
// 3 = lucky with at least one three of a kind AND at least one pair
// 2 = lucky with a three of a kind OR TWO pair
// 1 = lucky with at least one pair (or all of the above)
// 0 = super euphoric mode
if (pairs >= 2) {
    System.out.println("You where lucky");
}else {
    System.out.println("You wher NOT lucky");
}
```

Notes:

- You'll be rolling 2 times in this case, I personaly prefer "counter = 1; counter <= 2".
- Wrapping this in an Outcome class is indeed a better way of working, but I assume you're still learning java?

Comment: Damn, I've copied the single &

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work. It still outputs You are lucky when theres still one pair/triple and a nothing roll. It is supposed to roll twice. Yes i am still learning java right now

Comment: I see you did pair += 3 which you shouldn't. The pairs +2 makes it so that if you have one three of a kind you're considered lucky (irregardles of the next throw). The pairs + 1 print you're lucky when you have 2 pairs on two rolls. Remove pairs +=3 from your code

Comment: Also, make sure that int pairs is declared before the for loop.

Comment: if you want lucky when the result is: three of a kind|pair or pair|pair then change pairs+=2 to pairs+=1

Comment: I've added some comments so you can comprehend the code better and make changes accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to literal check if a A is different from B, you can use `A != B`, so you can check if `A != B && B != C` to output that you are not lucky.