# For-Loop and Arrays Java

Tags: arrays, for-loop

Can anyone explain to me in words what the code after 'for' exactly means?  I'm confused with the mixing of int and booleans within 'for' (still a beginner). It's about checking whether two arrays have the same values in the same sequence. Thanks in advance:

```
public static boolean equal(int[] a1, int[] a2) { 
if (a1.length != a2.length) { 
return false; 
} boolean equal = true;
for (int i = 0; i < a1.length && equal; i++) { 
equal &= a1[i] == a2[i]; 
}
return equal; 
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14

Answer (score 1):

The for loop consists of 4 parts:

```
for(initialisation; condition; increment/decrement) {
  body
}
```

Where **initialisation** is the part where you initialise variables which are in scope throughout the loop.

**Condition** is the boolean expression which if evaluated to true results in the execution of the **body**.

**Increment/decrement** is where you may change the value of any variable in the loop scope.

All 3 parts after the for keyword are optional, so you could create an infinite loop as shown:

```
for(;;) {
 System.out.println("body");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `equal &= a1[i] == a2[i];` is using the `&=` (logical-and assignment) operator, which is the same as `equal = equal & (a1[i] == a2[i]);`.  It combines the logical-and with the assignment operator.  This line can be parsed like this:

```
bool = (itself) AND (int == int)
bool = (itself) AND (another bool)
bool = (some bool value)
```

Be very careful with the `&` operator, since [it has two different meanings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5911145/4320665).  It means logical-AND for boolean types, but bitwise-AND for numeric types.  To make it clearer to read,  use `equal = equal && a1[i] == a2[i];` which also has the upside of short-circuit operation (which can save a few unnecessary comparisons).

On another note, there are a few redundancies in this loop.

```
boolean equal = true;
for (int i = 0; i < a1.length && equal; i++) { 
    equal &= a1[i] == a2[i]; 
}
```

The looping condition checks that the array still has elements AND that the previous element(s) have all matched.  Since the looping condition is also checking the boolean `equal`, there is no need to use the compound and-assignment operator.  A simple `equal = a1[i] == a2[i];` would work and even save the unnecessary `(true) & (something)` operation every loop iteration.  This works because the looping condition guarantees that `equal == true`, since the loop will stop execution otherwise.